# Calculate mean of columns from multiple dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three (or more) dataframe with the same header.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    's1': [230, 345, 222],
    's2': [235, 375, 292],
    's3': [210, 385, 260],
    's4': [10, 315, 120],
    's5': [110, 138, 560]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    's1': [130, 325, 232],
    's2': [218, 354, 234],
    's3': [217, 185, 340],
    's4': [180, 364, 450],
    's5': [140, 148, 120]
})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    's1': [30, 315, 542],
    's2': [235, 315, 22],
    's3': [216, 35, 260],
    's4': [910, 209, 720],
    's5': [11, 178, 360]
})
```

Here I want to take the mean of columns from different dataframe having same header. Expected answer is

```
mean = pd.DataFrame({
    's1': [130, 328.33, 332],
    's2': [229.3, 348, 182.67],
    's3': [214.3, 201.67, 286.67],
    's4': [366.67, 296, 430],
    's5': [87, 154.67, 346.67]
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do

```
sum([df1, df2, df3]) / 3
```

---

```
           s1          s2          s3          s4          s5
0  130.000000  229.333333  214.333333  366.666667   87.000000
1  328.333333  348.000000  201.666667  296.000000  154.666667
2  332.000000  182.666667  286.666667  430.000000  346.666667
```

Alternatively if you have variable number of rows you can do

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby(level=0).mean()
```